# Does vscode support removing spaces after opening and before closing curly braces now?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Code：

```
const a = {a: 'b'};
```

Then format it：

```
const a = { a: 'b' };
```

Does vscode support removing spaces after opening and before closing curly braces now?

Answer (score 7):

***Updated answer for newer vscode version***

As of VSCode 1.13, you can disable the automatic space insertion by setting:

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false
```

or

```
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false
```

---

***Original answer***

I work on JavaScript and TypeScript support for VSCode.

As of VSCode 1.9, we do not expose a setting for formatting spaces after and before curly braces. Support for this is being [tracked here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13275) and we'll pick up this formatting option once TypeScript exposes support for it

Comment: The issue you linked was closed and the configuration appears to work now (at least for JavaScript.)

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer to reflect this